# Google Analytics return corrupt data for after 19 march

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-developer-tools

I have an active Google Analytics account for which fetch data from Google Analytics through the Google Analytics API and show the data on dashboard page.

However for the past few days I have been having a problem with getting the corrupted data from API. I get this corrupted data after 19 march 2016. When I compare the data returned by the API with data in [google dev tools](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/) which also return the corrupted data for after 19 march.

However when I check the data before the 19 march then both API and google dev tools return correct data. When I match this data with Google Analytics website it returns the correct data for all dates.

So the point is why the google dev tools and API return corrupt data when Google Analytics website shows the correct data.

Edit: In my API query I requested for goals data, instead it returns Session value. this happens In both google dev tools and API both.

Comment: Can you give an example for what you mean by  "corrupted data" ?

Comment: in my API query I requested for goals data, instead it returns Session value. this happens In both google dev tools and API both.

Comment: when you say "Google Analytics dashboard"  do you mean the Google Analytics website or some third party application?

Comment: I think you need to post your actual query you are running.   If you request goals you will get goals you have an error someplace if you are seeing sessions.

Comment: it means when i view the reasults on this link :https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web

Comment: Thanks @DaImTo for everything,  I think the issue is fixed now. please check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36352623/google-analytics-return-corrupt-data-for-after-19-march/36356321#36356321

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the metrics value from ga:goal1starts to ga:goal1Completions. This have fixed the issue of showing corrupted value in API request.

Thanks